# Multiple Implementations of an Interface with setting the default values for some variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, interface

I am working on a MVC application with Code first Method. I have created a generic Interface with name IEntityBase. I have defined basic columns which will be used in all tables. I would like to assign default values to some of the columns so that when ever it will create a new row then those values will be assigned by default. As we can define then in each class constructor, but I want to assign them as generic so that if I will add any new column in future then I can do this.
Can I use the IOC for this?

for example

```
public interface IEntityBase
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
 }
```

The above Interface is the interface which is having 5 columns. I would like to assign the default value to IsActive as true, IsDeleted as False and Created as today's date.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try defining a base class instead.

Comment: Interfaces define a contract, not an implementation. Classes define implementations. As @Steven says, you need to use a base class that each thing inherits from. Make it abstract to avoid EF implementing it as STI.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your EF POCO domain classes, you could push the initialization to the overridden `SaveChanges` of your db context:

```
public class MyCustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        EntityState[] states = 
           new EntityState[] { 
              EntityState.Added, EntityState.Deleted, EntityState.Modified };

        // get all addded/deleted/modified entries
        foreach ( var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries() )
        {
            if ( entry.Entity is IEntityBase &&
                 states.Any( s => s == entry.State )
                )
            {
                IEntityBase e = (IEntityBase)entry.Entity;

                // some properties are always set
                e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;

                // other properties are set only for 
                // entities in specific state
                if ( entry.State == EntityState.Added )
                {
                    e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
        // save changes
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is actually a good solution for this particular use case (updating a created/modified date), but it should be noted that it would be a bad solution for implementing a "default" value on any other generic properties.